# Spring Security - Is there a way to check if you're in a secured request?

Tags: spring-security

I want to know if the request I am in is accessible anonymously, even if I am authenticated anyways.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you want to know if the user is authenticated, or do you want information about the current URL being requested?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing whether the URL being requested requires any spring security authorities, or can just be accessed anonymously. It appears I would need to implement a Spring Security filter to ask the AccessDecisionManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest idea is to extend [`AuthenticatedVoter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.html)  and override its [`vote()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.java#AuthenticatedVoter.vote%28org.springframework.security.core.Authentication,java.lang.Object,java.util.Collection%29)  method to save a flag in a thread-local whenever ConfigAttribute happens to be `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`. You can then inject your extended `AuthenticatedVoter` into your Spring Security stack.